# Will Application_Start event be fired if no request come in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, global-asax

Will Application_Start in Global.asax be fired before any request coming in?

Answer (score 1):

`Application_Start` as its name says fires when the application started (websites started / restarted). If the website is idle for a long time that when a request comes requires website to start again it will fire, otherwise it won't.

And yes it needs an incoming request to fire (that causes website to start)

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about ASP.NET Application Life Cycle:

> **Application_Start** Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life cycle of an application.

Answer (score 0):

Application_start is fires when the application is started/restarted. It will not fire when the website is idle for long time, and then request is come.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, the event will only be triggered by the very first request. If no one ever visited the site, the event would never fire.